# eclipse preference - grid layout confusion

Tags: eclipse, preferences, grid-layout

I try to build a part of an eclipse pref page which contains a table and add/remove-buttons. I have found some example code but I don't understand the following thing:

The method

```
protected void adjustForNumColumns(int numColumns) {
    ((GridData)top.getLayoutData()).horizontalSpan = numColumns;
}
```

sets the horizontal span for the parent (top) composite to the number of columns.

And the method

```
protected void doFillIntoGrid(Composite parent, int numColumns) {
    top = parent;

    // set layout
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    gd.horizontalSpan = numColumns;
    top.setLayoutData(gd); ... }
```

sets the layout with the horizontal span set to the number of columns.

Which method is used when and why is the number of columns somehow applied twice to a grid data object? It might be a pretty stupid question but I just started with the whole thing... Can anybody explain to me how it works? (Or even refer to a nice webpage where I can find an explanation)